# Tensor flow won't install using PIP? "No matching distribution found for tensorflow"

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, artificial-intelligence, command-prompt

[Command Prompt screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNJfi.png)

Pip won't install Tensorflow, I am using 64bit Python 3.11.1. I have download the Cuda toolkit. Using a 1050ti as the GPU. How do i get this to install?

Downloaded Anaconda but that doesnt seem to help either. Tried updating Pip but it is on its latest release. All I get is the "No matching Distribution" Error

Comment: Welcome! Can you please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Btensorflow%5D+Python+3.11

Comment: I don't believe this post deserves negative points since I had the same problem tonight and did not realize that TensorFlow updates every six months: see tf install requirements page -> "Last updated 2022-05-20 UTC"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no offifical release of tensorflow that is compatible version with Python 3.11 (see [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/)). Use Python 3.10 instead.